# Root finding algorithm for an analytic function

Tags: computational-complexity, na.numerical-analysis, computability-theory, computer-science, rootfinding

Given an analytic function $f(x)$. What is the best algorithm to find roots on the interval $[a,b]$ inside the radius of convergence> What is its complexity with respect to the length of input of the interval (i. e. length of numbers $a$ and $b$)? Does [the work, section 4](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81983170.pdf) give the bound for complexity of such algorithms?

Edit: zeros has to be real

Comment: It looks like we can use FFT, nlogn

Comment: @ katago, is this n a number, or the length of a number?

Comment: it is length of a number

Comment: @katago, may I ask you to describe the method?

Comment: @roignoirewg
Just a rough idea, stick [a,b] together to form S1, then use e(nx) to test and obtain information of different scales to obtain the root distribution

Comment: What does it mean "given an analytic function $f$"? In the most general case it would mean that you have some procedure that produces the coefficients up to any degree of the power series expansion in any point. // Why does the encoding of $f$ not contribute to the input length?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about optimality, but this seems to be a relatively recent survey:

> *Kravanja, Peter; Van Barel, Marc*, [**Computing the zeros of analytic functions**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0103927), Lecture Notes in Mathematics. 1727. Berlin: Springer. vii, 111 p. (2000). [ZBL0945.65018](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0945.65018).